# how can i set multiple alarms in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

i have a list view in which there are some toggle button (total 5) 
     the functionality of the app is  to set alrms for those dates which was clicked by user
     on toggle button checked i am sending data and and able to fetch data but didn't know what    to do next  i am able to make alarm ringing for single button but dont know **how to set it for multiple dates** the user can delete the alarms also
     here i am putting code
     pIndex is the index of button in list view

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                                 intent.setAction("action_d");
                                 intent.putExtra("day",day);
                                 intent.putExtra("month",month);
                                 intent.putExtra("state",state);
                                 intent.putExtra("count",mCount);
                                 Log.v("pending intent",""+pIndex);
                                 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, pIndex, intent, 1);
                                 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                              alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent );


    //on reciving class
    final String action = arg1.getAction();
    if ("action_d".equals(action)) {
            // do function d

                String day = arg1.getExtras().getString("day");
                int cmonth =arg1.getExtras().getInt("month");
                int state =arg1.getExtras().getInt("state");
                int count =arg1.getExtras().getInt("count");

                if(cmonth == month ){
                    Log.v("setting alarm for ","action d recived"+day);
                 if(day.equals(cDate))
                    {

                     vibrator.vibrate(2000);
                         notification.setLatestEventInfo(arg0, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
                         //notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                         notofManager.notify(NOTIF_ID,notification);

                         Intent mIntent = new Intent(arg0,DialogActivity.class); //Same as above two lines
                              mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                              arg0.startActivity(mIntent);
                    }
                }



        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set as many alarms as you want, the same way you are doing it now. You just need to make sure that each `PendingIntent` that you pass to the `AlarmManager` is unique. Unfortunately, the "extras" in the `Intent` are ignored when trying to determine the uniqueness of `PendingIntent`s. So you'll need to provide either a unique `requestCode` or a unique ACTION in the `Intent` to guarantee uniqueness of each `PendingIntent`.